# EasyRTC General authentication error

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, socket.io, easyrtc

I'm trying to do Video Call/Conferance app in NodeJs. When I enter the node page Im getting this error message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was Socket.io v1.0 doesn't support EasyRTC v1.0.11. 
You can see various module versions.

```
npm ls --unicode=false --depth=1
```

And the solution to downgrade socket.io from v1.0 to v0.9

```
npm install socket.io@0.9.x
```